# what is property of non-object?

Tags: php

I am not able to understand this error.

> PHP error: Trying to get property of non-object

It is showing error in this line:  `if ($data->num_rows > 0)`

I am new to php so I am having little difficulty to resolve this.

Source code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["token"]) && isset($_GET["email"])) {
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hackathon");

    $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_GET["email"]);
    $token = $connection->real_escape_string($_GET["token"]);

    $data = $connection->query("SELECT id 
                                FROM registration 
                                WHERE email='$email' 
                                AND token='$token' 
                                AND token <> '' 
                                AND expire> NOW()");

    if ($data->num_rows > 0) { //   Error in this line
        $str = "0123456789qwertzuioplkjhgfdsayxcvbnm";
        $str = str_shuffle($str);
        $str = substr($str, 0, 15);

        $password = sha1($str);

        $connection->query("UPDATE registration SET password = '$password', token = '' WHERE email='$email'");

        echo "Your new password is: $str";
    } else {
        echo "Please check your link!";
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
 ?>
```

Comment: The error means `$data` is not an object. and you are trying to read the property `num_rows` from it.

Comment: probably your $connection->query("SELEC... fails for some reason and don't return a valid object

Comment: ok.So ,I need to create an object for $data?

Comment: no .. you should try to understand why your  $connection->query("SELEC... fails

Comment: Just check you have a valid query.

Comment: and check also if you have a valid connection

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Check out what's `$data` by seeing `var_dump($data)` - I bet it's going to be `false`!

Comment: @scaisEdge If connection failed then the error would probabaly be on the first `real_escape_string()` call

Comment: Ok I will run the query in phpmyadmin and check error.I will use prepared parameterized statements frrom now on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  .. correct  ..

Comment: I think I have made mistake in table.I need to add one more column : expire.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/476